# How to delete the first occurence of a bibtex entry using sed?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, pattern-matching, bibtex

I would like to delete the first occurrence of an entry in a`bibtex` file
based on its id. For example, let's say we have this file:

```
@inproceedings{id1,
  author = "",
  title = "",
  ...
}

@inproceedings{id2,
  author = "",
  title = "",
  ...
}

@misc{id1,
  author = "",
  title = "",
  ...
}
```

And I would like to delete the first entry containing **id1**, so the output I would like
is:

```
@inproceedings{id2,
  author = "",
  title = "",
  ...
}

@misc{id1,
  author = "",
  title = "",
  ...
}
```

I want an automated way to do this using `sed` preferably. Until now I have this:

```
sed '/^@.*{id1/, /}/d' input_file
```

But this deletes all the occurrences in the file. Can you help me to find a way
to just delete the first one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'x;/./{x;b};x;/^@.*{id1/,/}/{/}/h;d}' file
```

Set a flag in the hold space once the first occurance has been deleted and if the flag is set ignore further lines to the end of the file.

There are two registers that can be utilized when writing sed commands. Sed will place the current line (minus the newline) in the Pattern Space (PS) and a second register is call the Hold Space (HS). `x` swaps the PS for the HS and `h` copies the PS to the HS. The sed one line script swaps the PS for the HS, checks the HS for any character `/./` and if this condition is true reswaps the HS for the PS and bails out. If the condition is not true the HS is reswapped for the PS and further commands are executed. A range condition is looked for `/^@.*{id1/,/}/` which is all lines inclusive between two strings and if found these lines are deleted but first if the current line is found to be the end condition this line is copied to the the HS. `/}/h`. Now subsequent lines will be ignored to the end of the file.

Comment: Cool! It works, but I don't understand what it does. Can you give me more info on how it works? I will also try to search for details in Google.. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much for the description! I was not aware of these register.. They seem very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Using awk you can do this with custom `RS` (record separator):

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '!/@inproceedings{id1/' f
@inproceedings{id2,
  author = "",
    title = "",
      ...
}

@misc{id1,
  author = "",
    title = "",
      ...
}
```

Comment: I would search for "id1" rather than assuming it's the first one.

Comment: Yes I can search but I though OP just wanted to remove first entry. Let me add that in my answer.

Comment: Right! I would like to delete something, based on the id as I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: But `id1` is there in 3rd entry also. Can we delete based on `@inproceedings{id1` text?

Comment: @ThanasisPetsas: Is this close to what you needed or need more filtering in awk condition?

Comment: I would like the regexp to be independent from the attribute `inproceedings` or `misc`.

Comment: Then you didn't answer my question. `id1` is found in 1st and 3rd record. How would you want to skip first entry only?

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/^@inproceedings{id1,/,/}/ d' YourFile
```

delete each line of the section (`/start/,/end/ action`)

Comment: But if both the entries with **id1** have the attribute `inproceedings` will be erased both of them, but I would like to delete only the first one..

Comment: Exact. Adapt your sample, i will try to adapt the code. I just see Potong already add a better code including this remark :-)

Answer (score 1):

sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line but for all other text manipulation you should use awk.

```
$ awk -v type="inproceedings" -v id="id1" -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -F'[@{,]' '!($2 == type && $3 == id)' file
@inproceedings{id2,
  author = "",
  title = "",
  ...
}

@misc{id1,
  author = "",
  title = "",
  ...
}
```

.

```
$ awk -v type="inproceedings" -v id="id2" -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -F'[@{,]' '!($2 == type && $3 == id)' file
@inproceedings{id1,
  author = "",
  title = "",
  ...
}

@misc{id1,
  author = "",
  title = "",
  ...
}
```

.

```
$ awk -v type="misc" -v id="id1" -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -F'[@{,]' '!($2 == type && $3 == id)' file
@inproceedings{id1,
  author = "",
  title = "",
  ...
}

@inproceedings{id2,
  author = "",
  title = "",
  ...
}
```

and if you want to select the blocks that match instead of the ones that don't match, just get rid of the `!` at the start of the condition.

All of the sed language constructs to manipulate multi-line blocks of code (i.e. everything except s, g, and p with -n) became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented so just ignore them all as you'll never need them. Get the book Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition by Arnold Robbins and spend you're time on that instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! This solution is great too. But as I asked for a preferable solution based on `sed` I accepted the answer of potong.
Nevertheless, `awk` is an amazing command/language! Thank you for the book suggestion too.

Comment: You're welcome. It's perfectly reasonable to accept a sed-based solution since you asked for one. Don't actually use it of course as that will lead to the oft-heard sed mantra `Cool! It works, but I don't understand what it does` and just TRY to modify it to do even the simplest thing differently or additionally, e.g. print a message to stderr when `author` is missing from a block :-).